# Check if logged in before submitting a form or onload a page

Tags: jquery

I have an editor which allows users to write articles if they are logged in. Therefor I'm using sessions.
If a user has started to write an article and is beeing interrupted for a while, it can happen, that the session isn't valid anymore. So the user will get the login-form while submitting the article, which means all the work is destroyed.

So I want to check on a submit of the form and if the user leaves the website if the user is logged in.

```
window.onbeforeunload = function() {
    return 'You have unsaved changes!';
    // Ask for saving or cancel --> prevent unload (if it is possible)
    // Check via AJAX if logged in otherwise show login-form
}
```

And:

```
$("#idForm").submit(function() {
    // Check via AJAX if logged in otherwise prevent submitting and show a login-form
}
```

1. Is that a proper way to solve the problem?
2. How do I know if the article is really changed? In the above example even a blank editor would lead to the info "you have unsaved changes"

Comment: You need to get the log like previously you have 319 chars and now 320 using 'KeyDown' event

Comment: ok. To make it simple I could catch a KeyDown-event to set a variable `var changed = 1`, right? So if the user pressed a button, is is assumed that he changed the content...

Comment: Yup and you should check in variable is changed or not before he unload the page